# Set something into Freemarker page by AOP in SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

To show the user's name on every Freemarker page, I could call `model.addAttribute` in every controller as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "index",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("currentUser", App.getCurrentUser());
    return "index";
}

#index.ftl
<div>${currentUser.userName}</div>
```

The calling would appear in everywhere of my code. It's really a nightmare. Is there any other way like AOP or Servlet Filter to set stuff into page?

Comment: Why dont you add your username in session ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use and interceptor for this, please check: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor

This kind of information it would be better to keep it on a session scoped bean holding the user profile, rather than reloading it for every HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks! I put user's info into session in the handler interceptor, then could get it from session directly in freemarker page without calling 'addAttribute' on model. Spring inject seesion value into model automatic! Furthurmore, I found another very useful attribute @SessionAttributes follow your guide. Thanks again!